# Handling Unicode in Spray-json with overriding the JsonPrinter

Tags: scala, spray, spray-json

while trying my first steps with Scala/Spray i ran into a problem with proper handling of unicode in spray-json.

For example: á is resulting \u00e1 in json. The resulting header indicates UTF-8 as well as the proper setting auf -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 which shows UTF-8 in the System.properties in Scala.

I found a possible solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14853087/cant-convert-unicode-symbols-to-cyrillic)

But i am shamed to admit i have no clue how to implement this because i am not adressing the JsonPrinter directly.
Here is what i have:

JsonProtocol:

```
object PersonJsonProtocol extends DefaultJsonProtocol {
  implicit object PersonJsonFormat extends RootJsonFormat[Person] {
    def write(per: Person) = JsObject(
        "name" -> JsString(per.name),
        "surname" -> JsString(per.surname),
        "addresses" ->  JsArray(per.addresses.toList.map(_.toJson))
    )
```

Simple Mapping in Person Class:

```
val simple = {
    get[String]("person_code") ~
    get[String]("name") ~
    get[String]("surname") map {
    case person_code~name~surname => 
    new Person(person_code, name, surname,  adressDao.findAll(person_code))
    }
  }
```

DB call within the routes:

```
ctx: RequestContext => ctx.complete(StatusCodes.OK, personDAO.findAll())
```

So my question would be, how can i overwrite the printString Method within the JsonPrinter. 
I would appreciate any help. Thank you in advance!

Comment: For posterity, this is the relevant issue in spray-json that needs to get resolved https://github.com/spray/spray-json/issues/46.

Comment: @DaveSwartz Thank you. So only way seems to find a unoffical workaround.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spray uses the marshallers provided by the trait `spray.httpx.PlayJsonSupport` to marshall Play json values. Within that trait, it defines a marshaller for any type that has a `Writes` implicitly available in scope.

```
implicit def playJsonMarshaller[T: Writes](implicit printer: JsValue => String = Json.stringify) = ???
```

As you can see, at least in version 1.3.1, you can override how a JsValue is converted to a string by providing an implicit `Function1[JsValue, String]` in scope. For example, defining the following method in scope of your `PersonJsonProtocol` using the solution linked in your question as the implementation should give you the desired results.

```
implicit def noUnicodeEscPrettyPrinter(json: JsValue): String = NoUnicodeEscPrettyPrinter(json)
```